# Events for DropDown placed inside Excel

Tags: c#, excel, excel-dna, vba

I am creating several DropDowns in Excel sheet using ExcelDNA, NetOffice and C#. Dropdowns are shown correctly, however I can't figure out how to bind an event each time the selection is changed. As you notice bellow I am binding to SheetChange event as suggested here http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/vasanthks/excel-dropdownlist-change-event-using-vba/ Any help would be appreciated.

```
for (int i = 1; i < col + 1; i++)
{
      var comboRange = ActiveSheet.Cells[2, i];

            var combobox1 = currentSheet.Shapes.AddFormControl(XlFormControl.xlDropDown,
                Convert.ToInt32(comboRange.Left), Convert.ToInt32(comboRange.Top), Convert.ToInt32(comboRange.Width), Convert.ToInt32(comboRange.Height));
            combobox1.Name = "cmb_" + i;
            combobox1.Placement = XlPlacement.xlMoveAndSize;
            combobox1.ControlFormat.DropDownLines = 1;
            combobox1.ControlFormat.AddItem("Item1", 1);

            combobox1.Application.SheetChangeEvent += new Excel.Application_SheetChangeEventHandler(ComboBox_Changed);

        }
    }


    private void ComboBox_Changed(object sender, Excel.Range rng)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Test", "Error",
                MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Control type you use- `XlFormControl.xlDropDown`- doesn't provide any solution for working with events. Instead you should use `OleObject` control. Here is a code snippet which could be a starting point:

```
var combobox1 = currentSheet.Shapes.AddOLEObject(ClassType:="Forms.ComboBox.1",...
```

For more information see [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff822655%28v=office.15%29.aspx). 
Next you should try to add `ComboBox1_Change()` event.

Comment: Hi Thanks, I have managed to convert combboxes to OleObject and raise events using : cb.Change += new MSForms.MdcComboEvents_ChangeEventHandler(CmdBtn_Click); However, I still strugling to detect which combobox is firing event and its value, any suggestion?